# How RxJava handles multiple data?

Tags: rx-java

The sequence of operations currently required is as follows:

1. Request type A list data from the server through Http Get
2. Then convert the list data of type A into list data of type B
3. Then request the existing type B list data from the local database
4. Then filter the data of the two lists of type B
5. Finally update the interface

How to write in RxJava？

```
 public void load(int type, Call call, OnLoadListener listener, Converter<A> converter) {
        Observable.concat(Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<List<A>>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<List<A>> emitter) throws Throwable {
                try {
                    Response response = call.execute();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        List<A> list = new Gson().fromJson(response.body().string(), new TypeToken<List<A>>() {
                        }.getType());
                        if (list != null) {
                            List<B> result = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
                            for (A a : list) {
                                result.add(converter.convert(a));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    emitter.onComplete();
                }
            }
        }), Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<List<B>>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<List<B>> emitter) throws Throwable {
                List<B> list=loadFromDb(assetsType);
                emitter.onNext(list);
                emitter.onComplete();
            }
        })).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Consumer<List<B>>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(List<B> list) throws Throwable {
                listener.onLoadSuccess(assetsType, list);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Research these rx-operators to use them in your rx-chain:

1. `switchMap()`/`flatMap()` [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)
2. `map()` [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html)
3. `merge()` [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html)

Note that you should use rx adapters to your frameworks that you use to fetch data from server and database.

Also to do some work in thread that you need, research `observeOn()`, `subscribeOn()` operators and rx-schedulers.

Finally, you need to update your interface in main thread using `subscribe()`

**UPDATED**

It should be something like this:

```
Single.merge(     
    yourService.getFromService().map { listA -> listA.toListB() },   
    yourDb.getFromDb() 
)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())     
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())      
    .subscribe(yourView::updateUi, ::handleError)
```

It is only example, in your case it can be looks different

Comment: @Richman, I updated answer with an example

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have put my code on it. I now want to remove the for loop and use the operator of rxjava to implement it. What should I do?

Comment: @Richman What do you do in your `for` loop?

Comment: Convert a list of type A to a list of type B. To convert I used a Converter interface.

Comment: @Richman You shouldn't use RxJava for converting entities. In my example `listA.toListB()` is common extension function. You can use Kotlin map function to convert list A to list B